# What is the number of all set permutations in a power set?

Tags: algorithm, discrete-mathematics

For a set of size `n`, the size of its power set is `2^n`. Generate all permutations for each element of the power set. The power set for set `{a, b}` is `{{}, {a}, {b}, {a,b}}`. Generate all permutations on each set, we can get `{(),(a),(b),(a,b),(b,a)}`. So the number of all subset permutation for a power set generated from a 2-element set is 5. And such a number for a 3-item set is 16. Is there a formula for this number defined in terms of `n`?

Comment: On OEIS: http://oeis.org/A000522

Comment: The link given by @DavidEisenstat answers my question. And it has a lot  of related references.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, consider the power set. The number of sets of size `k` (for some `0 <= k <= n`) in the power set is

```
n choose k = n! / (k! * (n - k)!)
```

Indeed, if we sum the number of sets for all `k`, we get `2^n`, see [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5Bn!/%28k!%2a%28n-k%29!%29,%20%7Bk,%200,%20n%7D%5D).

How many permutations does a set of size `k` have? Well, `k!`. So, if we plug that in, we loose the `k!` from the denominator and sum `n! / (n-k)!` for all `k`, which is

```
n! * Sum(1/k!, 0 <= k <= n)
```

Again, see the result by [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5Bn!/%28n-k%29!,%20%7Bk,%200,%20n%7D%5D).

Comment: I'm confused: did you mean to post the value of the second sum in addition to the link (as you did for the first)? Seems strange to omit it.

Comment: So it is `n! * Sum(1/k!, k=0..n)`. Is it possible to reduce this formula into a simple format?